# 2D Discrete Cosine Transform using 1D DCT

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, dct

I am trying to implement the 2D Discrete Cosine Transform to an image by using 
1D DCT operations. My output is incorrect if I compare it to the `dct2` MATLAB function. I don't understand what went wrong in my code and where it's happening.

If someone can point out the mistake or any other advice, that would be really helpful.

Here is my code written in MATLAB

```
% main function
signal=rand(100);
signal_dct=myDCT(signal);
figure; imshow((signal_dct));

% function to calculate 2D DCT of an image
function res=myDCT(signal)

    signal=double(signal);

    l=size(signal,1);

    res=zeros(l);  %initialize the final result matrix

    for k=1:l     %calculate 1D DCT of each row of image
        res(k,:)=mdct(signal(k,:));  
    end

    for k=1:l   %calculate 1D DCT of each column of image
        res(:,k)=mdct(res(:,k));
    end
end

%% function to calculate 1D DFT of a 1D signal
function res=mdct(signal)

    l=size(signal,1);

    for i=1:l

        if i==1   %for signal index of 1, alpha is 1/sqrt(l)
            alpha=sqrt(1/l);
        else   %for signal index of greater than 1
            alpha=sqrt(2/l);
        end

        j=[1:l];
        % summation calculates single entry of res by applying the  
        % formula of DCT on the signal
        summation=sum(sum(signal(j)*cos((pi*(2*(j-1)+1)*(i-1))/(2*l))));
        res(i)=alpha*summation;        
    end
end
```

Comment: It looks like you are using `cosd` with angles in radians. Use `cos` instead

Comment: thanks for pointing out that mistake. I have corrected it. But still the result is nothing like what i get from "dct2" matlab built-in function

Comment: is my main algorithm implementation correct because my result is very far off from the correct result?

Comment: I really don't know. Anyway, you will more likely get an answer if you post a reproducible example (code that can be run, with actual data that illustrates the problem)

Comment: I have included some main code lines to find the DCT for a random 2D array of numbers.

Comment: @LuisMendo - I figured out what was wrong. Take a look at my answer if you're interested.

Comment: @rayryeng Good job, great answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct in that the 2D DCT is separable.  You would just apply the 1D DCT to every row first, then take the intermediate result and apply it to the columns.  However, you have two fundamental mistakes.  Let's go through them.

## Mistake #1 - Size of DCT isn't correct

Specifically, look at this statement in your `mdct` function:

```
l=size(signal,1);
```

Because you are applying the DCT for each row, then each column, the above would only work if you are applying the DCT to the **columns**.  `size(signal,1)` would certainly give you the length of the input vector **if the input was a column**.  However, if your input was a **row**, then the output of `size(signal,1)` would be **1**.  Therefore, you should replace `size(signal,1)` with `numel` so that you are for sure going to get the total number of elements - regardless if the input is a row or column.

Also, if you want to make the code compatible to do the summation in the DCT loop, you should make sure that the input is a row vector **regardless**.  As such, do this instead:

```
l = numel(signal);
signal = signal(:).';
```

The first line determines how many elements we have for our input signal, and the second line ensures that we have a row vector.  This is done by `(:)` to unroll the elements into a column vector, then doing `.'` after to ensure we transpose the result to get a row vector.

## Mistake #2 - Summation statement isn't correct

Next, you're going to have to do element-wise multiplications in your summation to get what you're looking for.  You also don't need the extra `sum` call there.  It's superfluous.  Therefore, modify your summation statement to this:

```
summation=sum(signal.*cos((pi*(2*(j-1)+1).*(i-1))/(2*l)));
```

There's no need to do `signal(j)` because `j` spans the entire length of the vector, and you can just do that with `signal`.

---

Once I made these changes, and I did this on a smaller size matrix to ensure that we get the same results:

```
rng(123123);
signal=rand(7);
signal_dct=myDCT(signal);
signal_dct2 = dct2(signal);
```

The last line of code calls `dct2` so that we can compare the results from your custom function and what `dct2` gives us.

We get:

```
>> signal_dct

signal_dct =

    3.7455   -0.1854   -0.1552    0.3949    0.2182   -0.3707    0.2621
   -0.2747    0.1566   -0.0955    0.1415    0.3156   -0.0503    0.8581
   -0.2095    0.0233   -0.2769   -0.4341   -0.1639    0.3700   -0.2282
   -0.0282    0.0791    0.0517    0.4749   -0.0169   -0.4327    0.0427
   -0.4047   -0.4383    0.3415   -0.1120   -0.0229    0.0310    0.3767
   -0.6058   -0.0389   -0.3460    0.2732   -0.2395   -0.2961    0.1789
   -0.0648   -0.3173   -0.0584   -0.3461   -0.1866    0.0301    0.2710

>> signal_dct2

signal_dct2 =

    3.7455   -0.1854   -0.1552    0.3949    0.2182   -0.3707    0.2621
   -0.2747    0.1566   -0.0955    0.1415    0.3156   -0.0503    0.8581
   -0.2095    0.0233   -0.2769   -0.4341   -0.1639    0.3700   -0.2282
   -0.0282    0.0791    0.0517    0.4749   -0.0169   -0.4327    0.0427
   -0.4047   -0.4383    0.3415   -0.1120   -0.0229    0.0310    0.3767
   -0.6058   -0.0389   -0.3460    0.2732   -0.2395   -0.2961    0.1789
   -0.0648   -0.3173   -0.0584   -0.3461   -0.1866    0.0301    0.2710
```

---

As you can see, both results match up.  Looks good to me!

---

Just to be sure we are consistent, this is the full code listing for both your functions, with the modifications I made:

```
% function to calculate 2D DCT of an image
function res=myDCT(signal)

    signal=double(signal);

    l=size(signal,1);

    res = zeros(l);

    for k=1:l     %calculate 1D DCT of each row of image
        res(k,:)=mdct(signal(k,:));  
    end

    for k=1:l   %calculate 1D DCT of each column of image
        res(:,k)=mdct(res(:,k));
    end
end

%% function to calculate 1D DFT of a 1D signal
function res=mdct(signal)

    %// Change
    l = numel(signal);
    signal = signal(:).';

    for i=1:l

        if i==1   %for signal index of 1, alpha is 1/sqrt(l)
            alpha=sqrt(1/l);
        else   %for signal index of greater than 1
            alpha=sqrt(2/l);
        end

        j=[1:l];
        % summation calculates single entry of res by applying the  
        % formula of DCT on the signal
        %// Change
        summation=sum(signal.*cos((pi*(2*(j-1)+1).*(i-1))/(2*l)));
        res(i)=alpha*summation;        
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks a bunch! I was stuck on this with no way of knowing what went wrong. the mistakes you pointed out are small but which are probably recurring in my case. I'll remember them next time i write something in matlab. i cant thank you enough. :)

Comment: @bumpk_sync - my pleasure :) Thanks for the accept.  Also take a look at your DFT post.  I figured out what was wrong and corrected accordingly.